# Outputting email address from text files in Python, looking to make code a little more elegant

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python course on Coursera.  One of the assignments is to read input from a text file, extract the email addresses on lines starting with "From:", and then print both email addresses and the number of lines that start with "From:".  I got it to work after a little effort, but I wanted to see if my code can be cleaned up.

If I shouldn't worry so much about writing elegant code if I'm just in my second week of Python, you can go ahead and let me know.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
text = fh.read()
lines = text.splitlines()

count = 0
from_lines = list()

for line in lines:
    if 'From:' in line:
        count += 1
        from_lines.append(line)

email = list()

for line in from_lines:
    email = line.split()
    print(email[1])

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: `count` is the same as the length of `from_lines`, so you can get rid of `count` and replace it with `len(from_lines)` in the final `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the work done with only one loop like this:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
lines = text.readlines() #readlines creates a list of lines from the file

count = 0

for line in lines:
    if 'From:' in line:
        count += 1
        email = line.split()[1]
        print(email)

fh.close() # always close the file after use
print("There were {} lines in the file with From as the first word".format(count))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm going to have to take a closer look at the different functions I can use with what I know.

Answer (score 0):

1. You never `close` the file. Anyway you shouldn't be handling the files manually, and instead use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

   ```
   with open(fname) as as fh:
       ...
   ```
2. If you are going to iterate the file line-by-line, there is no need to save to memory the whole content of the file to a string. Files are iterators themselves and iterating over them gives the lines:

   ```
   for line in fh:
   ```
3. There is no need for two loops - if you just found there is an email in a line, why save it for later? Just use it right there!
4. You might check if the line [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) instead of using `in`.

All together might give:

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

count = 0
with open(fname) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('From:'):
            count += 1
            email = line.split()[1]
            print(email)  

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'd throw you an upvote if I could.

Looks like I have a lot to learn still.

Answer (score 0):

## Here:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

if not(fname): fname = "mbox-short.txt"

with open(fname) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
    count = 0
    from_lines = [line for line in lines if line.startswith('From:')]
    for line in from_lines:
        count += 1
        email = line.split()
        print(email[1])

print("There were",count,"lines in the file with From as the first word")
```

## Or...

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

if not(fname): fname = "mbox-short.txt"

with open(fname) as fh:
    lines = fh.readlines()
    from_lines = [line for line in lines if line.startswith('From:')]
    for line in from_lines: print(line.split()[1])

print(f"There were {len(from_lines)} lines in the file with From as the first word")
```